# Base Type to add two objects?

Tags: c#

I want to merge two objects by every property that is in both objects like:

```
// simplified pseudo code
foreach property which is in both objects (compared by name) do
target.Property += src.Property;
```

---

My current Method looks like this:

```
private void MergeStats(Object src, Object target)
{
    if (src == null || target == null) return;

    foreach (var srcProperty in src.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var targetProperty = target.GetType().GetProperty(srcProperty.Name);

        if (targetProperty == null) { continue; }
        if (targetProperty.GetValue(target).GetType() != typeof(UInt32)) { continue; }
        if (srcProperty.GetValue(src).GetType() != typeof(UInt32)) { continue; }

        var currentValue = (UInt32)(targetProperty.GetValue(target));
        var itemValue = (UInt32)(srcProperty.GetValue(src));
        var newValue = currentValue + itemValue;

        target.GetType().GetProperty(srcProperty.Name).SetValue(target, newValue);
    }
}
```

But I want to do it a bit more generic like this:

```
private void MergeStats<T>(Object src, Object target) where T : ??? { }
```

So my question is: Is there any Baste Type which defines that an object is *summable*?

Comment: `private void MergeStats<T>(T src, T target) where T : ISummable { }`?

Comment: `struct` will get you `int` and `float` (and friends), but its an imprecise constraint obviously.

Comment: You can do that with `dynamic` but that will also add `string`s and any other type that has the `+` operator. You need to narrow down the types that can be added. Or do you really want ALL the types that can be added?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no base type in the .NET framework which describes objects that are summable, or are composed of summable properties. A type constraint might help ensure that the `src` and `target` passed into the method are of the same type, so that your property comparison loop will work. This would simply be a `void MergeStats<T>(T src, T target)` where T will go un-used in the method body.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
private void T MergeStats<T, TSource, TTarget>(TSource source, TTarget target) where T : new()
{
    /* Use reflection to get a dictionary from T where the key is the property name and the value the type.  Now you can do the same for your source and target, lastly looping the dictionary from T and checking if key exists in either source or target dictionary, add property value to T*/
}
```